# Responsive build - positioning custom markers on a custom map

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive

I am using absolute positioning to place the markers on the map - but I am starting to run into a problem with the responsive mobile/desktop builds trying to ensure the markers correspond to the map.

I've tried to keep the map at a constant height - and look to shift the map in the horizontal plane.

[image]
[image]

//code

css

```
.mapwrap{
    position: relative;
    height: 900px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.mapholder{
    margin-left: -30%;
    position: relative;
}

.map{
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}   



.marker{
    position: absolute;
}

.marker .markerpointer{
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50%;
}

.marker.small .markerpointer{
    width: 60%;
    margin-left: -30%;
}


.pointer{
    /*background: orange;*/
    position: relative;
    width: 163px;
    height: 240px;
}

.markerimage{
    border-radius: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
}
```

html

```
<div class="mapwrap">
                                <div class="mapholder">
                                    <div class="markerholder">
                                        <div class="marker large" data-type="markers" data-size="large" data-pos-x="41%" data-pos-y="16%" style="left: 41%; top: 16%;">
                                            <div class="markerwrap">
                                                <div class="pointer">
                                                    <div data-type="curve"><svg width="195" height="195"><path id="wavy0" d="M-69.42135624665146,-44.57494023412153A82.5,82.5,0,1,1,5.051668046482832e-15,82.5L4.745506346695993e-15,77.5A77.5,77.5,0,1,0,-65.21400132261198,-41.873428704780835Z" transform="translate(97.5,97.5)" style="fill: none;"></path><text><textPath xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#wavy0" startOffset="0">some text that needs</textPath></text></svg></div>
                                                    <div class="coverimg"><img src="images/assets/square/0.jpg"></div>
                                                    <img class="markerpointer" src="images/marker.png">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="marker small" data-type="markers" data-size="small" data-pos-x="427" data-pos-y="287" style="left: 427px; top: 287px;">
                                            <div class="markerwrap">
                                                <div class="pointer">
                                                    <div data-type="curve"><svg width="129.796875" height="129.796875"><path id="wavy1" d="M-41.988087343500275,-26.960240840467254A49.8984375,49.8984375,0,1,1,3.0553980883414628e-15,49.8984375L2.7492363885546245e-15,44.8984375A44.8984375,44.8984375,0,1,0,-37.78073241946079,-24.258729311126558Z" transform="translate(64.8984375,64.8984375)" style="fill: none;"></path><text><textPath xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#wavy1" startOffset="0">some text that needs</textPath></text></svg></div>
                                                    <div class="coverimg"><img src="images/assets/square/1.jpg"></div>
                                                    <img class="markerpointer" src="images/marker.png">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="marker small" data-type="markers" data-size="small" data-pos-x="400" data-pos-y="517" style="left: 400px; top: 517px;">
                                            <div class="markerwrap">
                                                <div class="pointer">
                                                    <div data-type="curve"><svg width="129.796875" height="129.796875"><path id="wavy2" d="M-41.988087343500275,-26.960240840467254A49.8984375,49.8984375,0,1,1,3.0553980883414628e-15,49.8984375L2.7492363885546245e-15,44.8984375A44.8984375,44.8984375,0,1,0,-37.78073241946079,-24.258729311126558Z" transform="translate(64.8984375,64.8984375)" style="fill: none;"></path><text><textPath xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#wavy2" startOffset="0">some text that needs</textPath></text></svg></div>
                                                    <div class="coverimg"><img src="images/assets/square/2.jpg"></div>
                                                    <img class="markerpointer" src="images/marker.png">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="marker large" data-type="markers" data-size="large" data-pos-x="571" data-pos-y="651" style="left: 571px; top: 651px;">
                                            <div class="markerwrap">
                                                <div class="pointer">
                                                    <div data-type="curve"><svg width="195" height="195"><path id="wavy3" d="M-69.42135624665146,-44.57494023412153A82.5,82.5,0,1,1,5.051668046482832e-15,82.5L4.745506346695993e-15,77.5A77.5,77.5,0,1,0,-65.21400132261198,-41.873428704780835Z" transform="translate(97.5,97.5)" style="fill: none;"></path><text><textPath xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#wavy3" startOffset="0">some text that needs</textPath></text></svg></div>
                                                    <div class="coverimg"><img src="images/assets/square/3.jpg"></div>
                                                    <img class="markerpointer" src="images/marker.png">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <img class="map" src="images/map.png">
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: Show some code buddy?

Comment: _I've added some code - its a bit tricky to simplify it as a standalone example..

Comment: I am starting to complicate things with media queries from the mobile flavour to desktop

Comment: I've started a demo jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/QvNUF/1201/

Comment: The images are not loading in the fiddle, if you can provide a working example I can try to help.

Comment: I will try and put the images

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vxrjesL6/

Answer (score 0):

Using absolute positioning with fixed coordinates of `left` & `top` should work perfectly for you and the markers would align with the `img` you have attached.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nashcheez/vxrjesL6/2/

Refer code:

```css
.mapwrap {
  position: relative;
  height: 900px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.mapholder {
  position: relative;
}

.map {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}

.marker {
  position: absolute;
}

.coverimg img {
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: none;
}

.marker .markerpointer {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50%;
}

.marker.small .markerpointer {
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: -30%;
}

.pointer {
  /*background: orange;*/
  position: relative;
  width: 163px;
  height: 240px;
}

.markerimage {
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="mapwrap">
    <div class="mapholder">
      <div class="markerholder">
        <div class="marker large" data-type="markers" data-size="large" data-pos-x="41%" data-pos-y="16%" style="left: 370px; top: 137px;">
          <div class="markerwrap">
            <div class="pointer">
              <div data-type="curve">
                <svg width="195" height="195">
                  <path id="wavy0" d="M-69.42135624665146,-44.57494023412153A82.5,82.5,0,1,1,5.051668046482832e-15,82.5L4.745506346695993e-15,77.5A77.5,77.5,0,1,0,-65.21400132261198,-41.873428704780835Z" transform="translate(97.5,97.5)" style="fill: none;"></path>
                  <text>
                    <textPath xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#wavy0" startOffset="0">some text that needs</textPath>
                  </text>
                </svg>
              </div>
              <div class="coverimg"><img src="http://statici.behindthevoiceactors.com/behindthevoiceactors/_img/chars/plastic-man-young-justice-8.6.jpg"></div>
              <img class="markerpointer" src="http://www.theoldcounty.com/temp/marker.png">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="marker small" data-type="markers" data-size="small" data-pos-x="427" data-pos-y="287" style="left: 427px; top: 287px;">
          <div class="markerwrap">
            <div class="pointer">
              <div data-type="curve">
                <svg width="129.796875" height="129.796875">
                  <path id="wavy1" d="M-41.988087343500275,-26.960240840467254A49.8984375,49.8984375,0,1,1,3.0553980883414628e-15,49.8984375L2.7492363885546245e-15,44.8984375A44.8984375,44.8984375,0,1,0,-37.78073241946079,-24.258729311126558Z" transform="translate(64.8984375,64.8984375)"
                  style="fill: none;"></path>
                  <text>
                    <textPath xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#wavy1" startOffset="0">some text that needs</textPath>
                  </text>
                </svg>
              </div>
              <div class="coverimg"><img src="http://statici.behindthevoiceactors.com/behindthevoiceactors/_img/chars/plastic-man-young-justice-8.6.jpg"></div>
              <img class="markerpointer" src="http://www.theoldcounty.com/temp/marker.png">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="marker small" data-type="markers" data-size="small" data-pos-x="400" data-pos-y="517" style="left: 400px; top: 517px;">
          <div class="markerwrap">
            <div class="pointer">
              <div data-type="curve">
                <svg width="129.796875" height="129.796875">
                  <path id="wavy2" d="M-41.988087343500275,-26.960240840467254A49.8984375,49.8984375,0,1,1,3.0553980883414628e-15,49.8984375L2.7492363885546245e-15,44.8984375A44.8984375,44.8984375,0,1,0,-37.78073241946079,-24.258729311126558Z" transform="translate(64.8984375,64.8984375)"
                  style="fill: none;"></path>
                  <text>
                    <textPath xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#wavy2" startOffset="0">some text that needs</textPath>
                  </text>
                </svg>
              </div>
              <div class="coverimg"><img src="http://statici.behindthevoiceactors.com/behindthevoiceactors/_img/chars/plastic-man-young-justice-8.6.jpg"></div>
              <img class="markerpointer" src="http://www.theoldcounty.com/temp/marker.png">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="marker large" data-type="markers" data-size="large" data-pos-x="571" data-pos-y="651" style="left: 571px; top: 651px;">
          <div class="markerwrap">
            <div class="pointer">
              <div data-type="curve">
                <svg width="195" height="195">
                  <path id="wavy3" d="M-69.42135624665146,-44.57494023412153A82.5,82.5,0,1,1,5.051668046482832e-15,82.5L4.745506346695993e-15,77.5A77.5,77.5,0,1,0,-65.21400132261198,-41.873428704780835Z" transform="translate(97.5,97.5)" style="fill: none;"></path>
                  <text>
                    <textPath xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#wavy3" startOffset="0">some text that needs</textPath>
                  </text>
                </svg>
              </div>
              <div class="coverimg"><img src="http://statici.behindthevoiceactors.com/behindthevoiceactors/_img/chars/plastic-man-young-justice-8.6.jpg"></div>
              <img class="markerpointer" src="http://www.theoldcounty.com/temp/marker.png">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <img class="map" src="http://www.theoldcounty.com/temp/map.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: How will it handle in responsive mode -- for mobile -- I was concerned about rescaling etc..

Comment: Your version doesn't adapt in mobile/desktop variants

Comment: For mobile variants, you have to adjust the size of your markers and the map image accordingly and position your markers on the image using media queries. Refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: - sure - well this is the challenge - my current attempts are not working as ideally as possible. This is the issue I am having